# TFS - Change process template from custom to Agile

Tags: tfs

We originally upgraded TFS 2008 to TFS 2012 where i ran some batch files to add new features in old custom template. we are planning to migrate tfs 2012 to tfs 2013 and as part of this, also change our template from custom to Agile (latest). I have looked at the TFS Integration Platform and there are lots of people complaining about it. What should be the best approach i should take? we have 91 Team Projects literally and i don't want to do this manually.

Thanks

Comment: If you have 91 team projects I would suggest that you are doing it wrong ;) . You should also focus on consolidating team projects AFTER you have the PT sorted...

Comment: @MrHinsh: I know that shouldn't be the case but everyone had admin permissions and they just did what they felt like. we are now fine controlling TFS and as part of that we wanted to use Agile Process Template and probably use sharepoint (depending on how much work is involved) as well

Comment: 91 team projects is excessive! Do you have 91 completely independent products that don't share code, people, or work items?

Comment: no, we don't and i agree with you. i was wondering if you could tell me if it's worth it to create a new collection where we can use new process template for all the projects and also create them from scratch? history will be available in the old collection?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do it that way it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the process template is a simple affair once you get your head around the process.

http://nakedalm.com/upgrading-your-process-template-from-msf-for-agile-4-to-visual-studio-scrum-2-x/

Regardless of the change the process is the same.

1. Create a hybrid template with the target template + all the fields from the old template not in the target
2. Import hybrid template
3. Use Excel to migrate data between source only fields to new target fields
4. Import target template

Having done this a bunch i find it very easy, but it's a little tricky for noobs. I would recommend finding a Microsoft Visual Studio ALM MVP to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively have two options:

1. Bend the existing projects' process template into the shape of MSF Agile
2. Migrate each project to a new project with a new template.

Option 1 will be a reasonable amount of work depending on your original base template and may not be as clean an outcome as a brand new project would be but it should be pretty good.  You will not restructure, trim or consolidate the 91 projects as part of the process.  The upside is there should be no data loss as the projects will stay intact.  Once you have the new template definitions, you should be able to script this easily to run against all the projects.

Option 2 means you are creating a new project on the same server or a new server with the new template and migrating data.  Migrating to a new project means there will be some data loss depending on the options you go for.  For example, migrating source control to a new server using the Integration Tools will compress your history and it doesn't handle Test Cases well.  This option allows you to consolidate some of those projects to take advantage of the new Agile Portfolio functionality too.

TFS Integration Tools *may* work but they are by no means a sure fire winner and I generally try to avoid them if possible.  It could be worth a test run on a single team project over a weekend but it's going to be some work to map the fields between the templates and there are a lot of limitations.

You could look at [WitSync](https://github.com/giuliov/WitSync), [WitMorph](https://github.com/jstangroome/WitMorph) and [Total TFS Migration](https://totaltfsmigration.codeplex.com/)

If you're going for option 2 then if you can get away with it, using Excel to bulk migrate Work Items is quick, easy and effective.

This is a useful article if you go down this route
[Bulk Migrate Work Item Comments, Links and Attachments](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/bulk-migrate-work-item-comments-links-and-attachments)

ps. IMHO the Scrum template is generally a better choice than MSF Agile. Good luck!